# Detecting a tendinopathy by touching

Tags: tendinopathy

A patient complains about light background pain around the lateral epicondyle of the humerus, likely a tendinopathy such as a tendinosis. MRIs show nothing abnormal. Can a physician or physiotherapist detect by touching that there is a tendinopathy or that the tendon is not properly healed?

Let's assume that the patient saw the physician one hour after doing the MRI, and that the patient has neither swelling nor heat.

Comment: Gold standard is not examination!